# If $f$ is a loop in $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, then is $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ a compact set in $[0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology

If $f$ is a loop in $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, then is $f^{-1}(\{x\})$, $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n}$, a compact set in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: It's a closed subset of a compact space.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer Why is $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ closed in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous, and $\mathbb{S}^n$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

Since $\mathbb S^n$ is Hausdorff, singletons are closed.

The loop $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb S^n$ is a continuous map, so the inverse image of closed sets is closed, in particular $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is closed.

But $[0, 1]$ is compact and closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Conclude that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is compact.

Comment: Clearing the queue of unanswered questions deserves great respect! +1